# batch file: copy the contents of one file to another file in different directories

Tags: batch, batch-file, cd, copy

I  want to create a batch file to combine the contents of two text files:

`c:\folder1\1.txt` with `c:\folder2\2.text` and then, append it to another file `c:\folder3\combine.txt`

Where the batch file (copy.bat) is. The structure of the directory is as follows:

```
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is A0AD-DC56
C:.
+---Folder 1
|   \---With
|       \---Name
|           \---Path
|               \---Too
|                   \---Large
|                           1.txt
|
+---Folder 2
|   \---With
|       \---Name
|           \---Path
|               \---Too
|                   \---Large
|                           2.txt
|
\---Folder 3
    \---With
        \---Name
            \---Path
                \---Too
                    \---Large
                            Combine.txt
                            Copy.bat
```

I tried:

```
copy "c:\folder1\1.txt" + "c:\folder2\2.text" "c:folder3\combine.txt"
```

Is there any alternative way to change the directory using the `cd` command to change the directories and combine the files instead of giving the path of the files?

Comment: What do you mean by "path name too large"? For comfort? Readability? Error messages? How do you imagine `cd`ing would differ from specifying the path?

Comment: I want to create some text files by copy command and I want to shorten the path for both comfort and readability. I suppose that it may a way to combine `cd` commands (cd ..  , cd ..\.. , etc)and `copy` instead of giving the whole path.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell:

```
Set-Location 'c:\Folder3'
$FIle1 = 'c:\Folder1\1.txt'
$FIle2 = 'c:\Folder2\2.txt'
(Get-Content $File1 ) + (Get-Content $File2 ) | Set-Content 'Combine.txt'
```

Copy the above into a text editor $ save in Folder3 as `MyCopy.ps1`. Launch by specifying as path: `c:\FOlder3\Mycopy.ps1` or `.\MyCopy.ps1`

Answer (score 1):

`Edit /*`

**Obs.:** About your file **`copy.bat`**, try not to use a `command` name for your batch or always use it/execute it with its extension when using the command line, but by clicking you will not have any problems: `> copy.bat`

---

```
@echo off 

set "_x="<nul && goto :_main
     
:_subst
for %%d in (Z,Y,X,W,V,U,T,S,R,Q,P,O,N,M,L,K,J,I,H,G,F,E)do >nul 2>&1 (
     %__APPDIR__%subst.exe %%~d: "%~1" && set "_rmv_drv_%~2=%%~d" && (
         set "_dir_%~2=%~1" && exit /b ) )

:_main
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

for %%i in ( 
     "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files"
     "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp\NVIDIA Corporation"
     "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp\Discord Crashes"
     )do set /a "_x+=1+0" && call :_subst "%%~si" !_x!
     
copy /y /b "!_dir_1!\1.txt" + "!_dir_2!\2.txt" "!_dir_3!\Combine.txt.txt"

rem :: or..

copy /y /b "!_dir_1!\1.txt" + "!_dir_2!\2.txt" +  "!_dir_3!\Combine.txt" "!_dir_3!\Combine.txt"

%__APPDIR__%subst.exe

rem :: do more task... after this, you can remove your tmp drivers ::
for /L %%L in (1 1 !_x!)do %__APPDIR__%subst.exe /D !_rmv_drv_%%L!: && (
   echo\^| Removed ^| Drive: !_rmv_drv_%%L!:\:  =^>  !_dir_%%L!    ) 

endlocal & goto :eof
```

**1.** To handle very long paths, you can try using the:

```
subst avaliable-drive "c:\folder\far\far\away"
subst Z: "c:\folder\far\far\away"
```

**2.** When it is no longer needed, remove `drive` associated to your folder path:

```
subst avaliable-drive "c:\folder\far\far\away"
subst Z: "c:\folder\far\far\away"
subst /D  Z:
```

- **Obs.:** I think I got lost in my order of listings for the steps, please ignore this part :)

---

**3.** Before using **`subst`**, you can shorten the paths of the folders, and also organize the way in which the creation will take place, already enabling the future removal of the created drives, in order to automate these steps:

**3.1:** Use a `for` loop to list your folders neatly, based on my example folders

```
for %%i in ( 
     "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files"
     "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp\NVIDIA Corporation"
     "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp\Discord Crashes"
     )do ...
```

**3.2:** You use **`%%~si`** in loop to expand/change the path present in the variable **`%%i`**, for shortening to the format of path/string to **`Short 8.3`**, if it exists:

```
for %%i in (.)do set ... && ... "%%~si"...
```

- **Obs.:** You can check if this feature is enabled, and if it is not enabled,
  but, this will require admin right on execution:

```
 > %__APPDIR__%fsutil.exe 8dot3name query c:
 The registry state is now: 0 (Enable 8dot3 name creation on all volumes).

 > %__APPDIR__%fsutil.exe behavior set disable8dot3 0
 The volume state is: 0 (8dot3 name creation is enabled).
 The registry state is: 0 (Enable 8dot3 name creation on all volumes).

 Based on the above settings, 8dot3 name creation is enabled on C:
```

**3.3:** Use a counter to facilitate the use of the folders sequentially and also use it to define the variables and remove them when no longer needed

```
for %%i in (.)do set /a "_x+=1+0"...
```

**3.4:** Use **`label`** for test each drive (in reverse order) to find one for use with **`subst`**, sending as a parameter, the path of the folder already shortened (**`%%~si`**), and it holds the counter value (**`!_x!`**)

```
call :_subst "%%~si" !_x!
```

**Obs.:** Incrementing your counter before calling the label/function

```
)do set /a "_x+=1+0" && call :_subst "%%~si" !_x!
```

**3.5:** Use a reverse order loop in your **`label/function`** to test the availability of a driver, and when found, it will be signaled by the **`&&`** (**`return 0`**) operator, the subsequent execution will occur (explained later)

```
:_subst
for %%d in (Z,Y,X,W,V,U,T,S,R,Q,P,O,N,M,L,K,J,I,H,G,F,E
)do subst %%~d: "%~1" && execute ... 

call :label  <parameter 1>           <parameter 2>
call :_subst "the sort path in loop" counter
call :_subst "%%~si"                 !_x!
```

**3.6:** Within the function, it will use the shortened path (**`%~1`**), trying letter by letter to associate with the path (parameter 1), when this execution **`returns 0`**, then it will also use the parameter 2 (**`%~2`** == sequential number), to save the letter of the associated drive deform to allow removal when no longer needed, also exiting the loop and function immediately:

```
:_subst
for %%d in (Z,Y,X,W,V,U,T,S,R,Q,P,O,N,M,L,K,J,I,H,G,F,E)do >nul 2 >&1 (
     %__APPDIR__%subst.exe %%~d: "%~1" && set "_rmv_drv_%~2=%%~d" && (
         set "_dir_%~2=%~1" && exit /b ) )
```

**3.7:** The actions that return from the label are basically concatenation of variables and values ​​that were defined in sequential order together with the respective associations for the folders by assigning a unit/driver:

```
:_subst
      %__APPDIR__%subst.exe Z: "C:\Users\ecker\...~1" && set "_rmv_drv_1=%%~d" && (
         set "_dir_1="C:\Users\ecker\...~1" && exit /b ) )

rem :: some possible variable results for drives Z:, X: and Y:
Folder Variables: 
!_dir_1! == "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp\DISCOR~1"
!_dir_2! == "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp\NVIDIA~1"
!_dir_3! == "C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp\TEMPOR~1.NET"

Driver Save/Remove Variables:
!_rmv_drv_1! == Z:\
!_rmv_drv_2! == Y:\
!_rmv_drv_3! == X:\
```

**3.8:** Now that you have your variables, it is possible to make use of each one, which were created sequentially, and pass your commands with the respective use, and when you finish the tasks, you can remove (should!) the associated drives (explained next):

```
copy /y /b "!_dir_1!\1.txt" + "!_dir_2!\2.txt" "!_dir_3!\combine.txt"
```

**3.8:** Now it's time to remove the associated units, and knowing that they are in numerical order, you can make use of a `For /L` loop, that within a defined range, it will increase a value up to a maximum value (elements also pre defined, ***`start, step, end`***), and concatenating with the variables, it is possible to recover the value and pass the commands for removal:

```
for /L %%L in (1 1 !_x!)do %__APPDIR__%subst.exe /D !_rmv_drv_%%L!: && (
   echo\^| Removed ^| Drive: !_rmv_drv_%%L!:\:  =^>  !_dir_%%L!    )

Driver Save/Remove Variables:
!_rmv_drv_1! == Z:\  %%L == 1
!_rmv_drv_2! == Y:\  %%L == 2
!_rmv_drv_3! == X:\  %%L == 3

| Removed | Drive: Z:\:  =>  C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp\TEMPOR~1.NET
| Removed | Drive: Y:\:  =>  C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp\NVIDIA~1
| Removed | Drive: X:\:  =>  C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp\DISCOR~1
```

---

**Obs** However, if your path is much more distant than the Far Far Away in Shrek, all this options can fatally fail, see the limitations:

- Path length in cmd:

  - **[The CMD shell will fail to read an environment variable if it contains more than 8,191 characters](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**
    If this is the case, I suggest migrating your efforts to PowerShell:
- Path length in PowerShell:

  - **[The theoretical max length of a String is 2147483647](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/58201057-41d3-492e-9ddc-a553f1cd199c/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-characters-or-limit-for-powershell-string-variable-we-can-pass?forum=sharepointgeneral)**

**3.9** So, you may need to check if this **[answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1574241/969781)** can solve this to you :

I often had problems with path lengths, most of which were resolved with cmd, (at the time it was what I had), but during those times, the most experienced users here can help you better ... good question yours, thank you..

`Edit */`

---

---

It looks like you forgot the **`\`** and using the full path in the destination file too:

```bat
copy "c:\folder1\1.txt" + "c:\folder2\2.text" "c:\folder3\combine.txt"
```

**Obs.: 1** When you invoke your bat from any folder or drive, command-line interpreter (cmd.exe) has to define a working directory, but your command not providing any drive or folder, only one file name isolated.

```bat
copy /b "c:folder1\1.txt" + "c:folder2\2.text" combine.txt
```

**Obs.: 2** To define your working directory for your file copy `destination` and other possible actions of your bat in `folder3` add the respective drive / folder using "**`cd /d "drive\folder"`** or, if it is the same **"`drive/folder`** as your bat, you can use **`cd /d "%~dp0"`** or **`pushd "%~dp0"`**

[image]

- Adding the **`CD`** or **`Pushd`** to define your work directory and which folder is the same folder where your bat will start and run:

```bat
@echo off 

cd /d "%~dp0"

rem :: or... 
pushd "%~dp0"

rem :: or... 
cd /d "folder3"

copy "c:\folder1\1.txt" + "c:\folder2\2.text" "combine.txt"
rem :: more commands here
popd
```

---

- Without adding the **`CD`** or **`Pushd`**, you can use `set` for your folders:

```bat
@echo off 

set "_var_1=c:\folder1"
set "_var_2=c:\folder2"
set "_var_3=c:\folder3"

copy "%_var_1%\1.txt" + "%_var_2%\2.txt" "%_var_3%\Combine.txt"
```

[image]

---

Some further reading:

- cd help:  **[`cd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**
- set help:  **[`set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**
- popd help:  **[`popd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)**
- copy help: **[`copy /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html)**
- pushd help:  **[`pushd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)**